# Active record error when migrating from rails 2.3 to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am migrating from a rails 2.3 application to Rails 3.1, i am getting this error when i try to save a record. This was not happening earlier and i am not sure what could be the reason, any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Here are previews of my models

**

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :orders
end
```

**

**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
has_many :items, :dependent => :delete_all
end
```

**

**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base 
belongs_to :order
validates_presence_of :order_id
end
```

**

Below is error message log when i try to save

**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Items order can't be blank
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:194:in `transaction'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/activerecord-3.1.12/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
    from (irb):16
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/branch/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1
```

**

When i try to save Order via console. the primary key is getting saved as nil.

**`o = st.orders.new(:store_order_id => "1M",:date_time => Time.now)`**

here is what i see when i

```
o.save

#<Order id: nil, store_order_id: "12121M", date_time: nil>
```

below is a preview my Order Controller Create code

```
def create
@order = @store.orders.new(params[:order])
@order.save

end
```

Comment: The error talks by itself.  You're having a model errors with a validation preventing orders to be present, and for some reason you're not doing it.

Comment: Give some preview of your model. Specially where you are validating columns

Comment: Hello Hernan Velasquez, thats correct, but this was not happening before migrating to rails 3.1 it was working in rails 2.3, hence i am not sure what is going wrong

Comment: Then you shld be posting your model code

Comment: I have added my model code

Comment: validates :order, presence: true Try this syntax...Btw How are you trying to save item?

Comment: Hello vamsi, i am not saving item i am saving order like order.save

Comment: Hi Vamsi, it gives the same error when i use validates :order, presence: true

Comment: Can you show the steps what you did in the ruby console? I guess we are missing data here. Can you post Order controller create and update methods too?

Comment: Hi vamsi, i have added the console code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82605/discussion-between-opensource-ios-and-vamsi-krishna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue is that you can't do this:

```
validates_presence_of :order_id
```

in the Item model.  The reason is simple: the Order id is created after validation and thus doesn't exist.

There are a couple of things to do:

1. add inverse relationships
2. Change your validation to simply check for the presence of "order", not "order_id"

Here's the code:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :items, :inverse_of => :order, :dependent => :delete_all
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :order, :inverse_of => :items
  validates_presence_of :order
end
```

Comment: By the way, I have no idea why you're moving to 3.1 unless you're upgrading incrementally.  Please go to the latest 4.2 before you're done.

Comment: Yes, i am upgrading incrementally, but can you tell me why the same code works in rails 2.3 and not in rails 3.1?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know or care why it works in 2.3, but given your code it should have given an error.  What I've given you is correct, that's all that matters.

Comment: Also, you might be new here so I'll mention this.  You should upvote my answer after confirming that it is correct.  Thanks.

Comment: this solved the issue but its mysterous that it worked in rails 2.3 and not in rails 3.1